# Pictures getting lower

Tags: php, image

When I upload a picture from the admin panel, it gets shown, but the pictures get lower. I mean the first picture is in the right place, the second is a little lower than the first, then the third is even lower than the second, and so on...

My code:

```
<?php
    include 'navbar.php';   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Couture Collection</title>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'middle.php';
?>
<br>
<style type="text/css">
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1,
h1+p {
    margin: 30px 15px 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1+p a {
    color: #333;
}
h1+p a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
    margin: 60px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h2 span {
    margin-left: 1em;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 85%;
}
.column {

    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.column::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.column div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.column div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
figure {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
figure:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;
}



/* Zoom In #1 */
.hover01 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover01 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

/* Zoom In #2 */
.hover02 figure img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover02 figure:hover img {
    width: 350px;
}

/* Zoom Out #1 */
.hover03 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover03 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

/* Zoom Out #2 */
.hover04 figure img {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover04 figure:hover img {
    width: 300px;
}

/* Slide */
.hover05 figure img {
    margin-left: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover05 figure:hover img {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* Rotate */
.hover06 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.4);
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover06 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(0) scale(1);
}

/* Blur */
.hover07 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover07 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
}

/* Gray Scale */
.hover08 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover08 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

/* Sepia */
.hover09 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: sepia(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover09 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: sepia(0);
    filter: sepia(0);
}

/* Blur + Gray Scale */
.hover10 figure img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover10 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
}

/* Opacity #1 */
.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

/* Opacity #2 */
.hover12 figure {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.hover12 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover12 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

/* Flashing */
.hover13 figure:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: flash 1.5s;
    animation: flash 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: .4;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

/* Shine */
.hover14 figure {
    position: relative;
}
.hover14 figure::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 100%);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.hover14 figure:hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: shine .75s;
    animation: shine .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
    100% {
        left: 125%;
    }
}
@keyframes shine {
    100% {
        left: 125%;
    }
}

/* Circle */
.hover15 figure {
    position: relative;
}
.hover15 figure::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover15 figure:hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: circle .75s;
    animation: circle .75s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>



        <?php
        include 'admin/connect.php';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row = $run->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $row['id'];


        ?>



        <div class="column">
            <a href="<?php echo 'product.php?id='.$id;?>"><img src="<?php echo 'inventory_images/'.$id; ?>" style="width: 300px;height: 300px;padding-left: 50px;"/></a><br><br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php

    }
    ?>
<br>
    <br>
<?php
include 'sale.php';

?>
<br>

    <br>
    <footer>
        <?php
            include 'footer.php';
        ?>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have a link to the page?